# How to handle dynamic xpaths

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to select the text that has returned based on my search operation.
For every search xpaths will get differ. These are various xpaths that are returned on search

```
.//*[@id='messageBoxForm']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/input

.//*[@id='messageBoxForm']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/strong
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place it in a try-catch-block and use the first x-path in your try, catch the "NoSuchElementException" Selenium could throw and then try the other x-path.

Based on the criteria you posted this should do the job.

```
WebElement element;
try {
    element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("xyz"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("abc"));
}
```

... do things with your element

Comment: If it has only two elements then we can place.But it has many elements  .//[@id='messageBoxForm']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[i]/div[2]/strong where i have written "i " the value get increases not sure how many elements will present so .

Comment: Then define your x-pathes in a list of strings, iterate over it and break the loop if it found an element and otherwise catch the exception, and make the next step in your iteration. This method does not feel good and you should consider a different solution as this can select elements you did not want to select if the x-path matches something really different.

Comment: You have need to have some parent-element. That is where you start to notice changes in the x-pathes. At this point you can use "webDriver.findElements" (notice the "s" at the end) to find a list of elements. From there you need something you can iterate over the different possible x-pathes until one matches. Also I would go the other way around and iterate over the x-pathes. Those should be known to you to a certain level.

Comment: Can anyone explain  how to write a custom xpath by using start with or contains  for the above mentioned  xpaths